# Convert Google Place Types into String

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm working on my code to check the types of the place base on place details following this document (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Place).

I manage the value from List, the question is how I can display the string for example place a is restaurant, place be is bank from the class. Or should I create an array based on the document? Please advise.

```
final Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(this, data);
final List<Integer> types = place.getPlaceTypes();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), types.get(0).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Regards, -sea-

Comment: post your code. The question will be down voted other wise for posting an incomplete question!

Comment: done, i want to retrieve the type using any code rather that create array list

Comment: Are you looking to retrieve the corresponding name for the int values?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do, I put on the msgbox for testing purpose

Comment: Thanks all, I got it already. Up and running :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* do something as crazy as:

```
    int myPlaceType = 1;

    Field[] fields = Place.class.getDeclaredFields();

    for (Field field : fields) {
        Class<?> type = field.getType();

        if(type == int.class) {
            try {
                if(myPlaceType == field.getInt(null)) {
                    Log.i("Testing", "onCreate: " + field.getName());
                    break;
                }
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

This will print TYPE_ACCOUNTING to your Android console.

Where myPlaceType is the `int` place type...
Not perfect, and I hope someone has a better suggestion!

Gav

Comment: Thanks @Gavin, my intention is actually to update current marker to custom icon, that's why I tried to get details of the place.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the answer